# Medical history and investigation for asking questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have been seeing some questions like [here](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/24439/uti-in-older-people) which presents real cases.

Some questions which can possibly be asked from here are like *why this drug is preferred ?* , *why this investigation is done?* ,*how this investigation help us?* etc. But to answer these questions, I think we require a proper medical history. We also need to know other lab investigations done for eg. CBC, LFT, KFT ; radiological investigations and diagnosis made etc.

So, are there any suggestions regarding inclusion of history and others investigations to be posted with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, questions requesting medical advice for specific cases are strictly off topic here. If there appears to be a real person involved and the question asks for advice, the question will be closed (the question you cited has now been closed for this very reason).

This is a very old and well settled debate on this site. [For the reasons outlined here](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/8212), we cannot, and will not, give personal medical advice.

You can reopen that debate if you wish, but note the disclaimer in bold on the site's main page (upper right yellow box). Even if we agreed to allow medical advice in some circumstances, I don't think stackexchange management would allow it.